# Criar uma Div para cada resultado de requisição

Tags: javascript, http-request

Como fazer para criar uma div para cada resultado obtido através de uma requisição em uma API, a API em utilização é "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com". A minha intenção é replicar uma div "caixaPost" para cada resultado obtido.

```js
var usuarioId = document.getElementById("usuarioId");
var postId = document.getElementById("postId");
var tituloPost = document.getElementById("tituloPost");
var descricaoPost = document.getElementById("descricaoPost");

var idUsuario = document.getElementById("idUsuario");
document.getElementById("botaoBuscaId").onclick = RequisicaoPorUsuario;

function RequisicaoPorUsuario() {

    var HttpClient = function () {
        this.get = function (aUrl, aCallback) {
            var anHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
            anHttpRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (anHttpRequest.readyState == 4 && anHttpRequest.status == 200)
                    aCallback(anHttpRequest.responseText);
            }
            anHttpRequest.open("GET", aUrl, true);
            anHttpRequest.send(null);
        }
    }

    //puxa o id do usuário informado
    var usuarioId = idUsuario.value;

    //da um alert pra verificar se ta puxando corretamente
    alert(usuarioId);

    //concatena a url de busca com o ID do Usuário informado
    var url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/?userId="+usuarioId;

    var client = new HttpClient();
    client.get(url, function (response) {
        var response1 = JSON.parse(response);
        console.log(response);

        // exibe todos os dados buscados em uma janela de Alert
        alert(response);

        // Aqui eu desejo criar um laço que crie uma janela de post para cada "resultado" obtido...
    });
}
```

```css
body{
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
.caixaPost {
    float: left;
    background-color: rgb(138, 180, 75);
    width: 50%;
    height: auto;
}
.caixaUsuarioId {
    padding: 1%;
    float: left;
    margin: 1%;
    background-color: aliceblue;
}
.caixaPostId {
    padding: 1%;
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    margin: 1%;
    background-color: aliceblue;
}
.caixaTituloPost {
    padding: 1%;
    width: 96%;
    float: left;
    margin: 1%;
    background-color: white;
}

.caixaDescPost{
    padding: 1%;
    width: 96%;
    float: left;
    margin: 1%;
    background-color: white;
    text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilo.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Teste Estágio - 2019</title>
</head>

<body>
    <button id="botaoBuscaId">Buscar por id</button>
    <input type="text" id="idUsuario">
    <div class="caixaPost" id="caixaPost">

        <div class="caixaUsuarioId">Id Usuário:
            <span id="usuarioId">X</span>
        </div>
        <div class="caixaPostId">Id post:
            <span id="postId">X</span>
        </div>
        <div class="caixaTituloPost">Título:
            <span id="tituloPost">XXX</span>
        </div>
        <div class="caixaDescPost">Descrição:
            <span id="descricaoPost">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
                standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it
                to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic
                typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset
                sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker
                including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="scriptAPI.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5w8bknmc/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Júlio Henrique ótima resposta só que no trecho abaixo devemos fazer uma leve alteração para que funcione como esperado

```
        // Aqui eu desejo criar um laço que crie uma janela de post para cada "resultado" obtido...
        let element = ""; // (Antes  let element = "";
        for (let index = 0; index < response1.length; index++) {
            element += ` // (element = `) Dessa forma os itens vão ser acumulados em vez de se sobreescrever
              <div>
                <h1>title: ${response1[index].title}</h1>
                <p>body: ${response1[index].body}</p>
              </div>
            `;

          }

   document.getElementById("divResultado").innerHTML = element;
```

Comment: Obrigado @Vinicius, mais uma dúvida, esses cifrões "$" não são referentes ao JQuerry? vetaram o uso de JQuerry no teste, se usar automaticamente estou desclassificado.

Comment: Se não puder utilizar com jQuery basta remover os ${} e  na utilização do response1[index].* usar o carácter ` antes e depois  dele concatenando a váriavel

Comment: Perfeito amigo, a sintaxe ficou assim, funcionou perfeitamente:

    var postUserId = response.data[i].userId;

    element += `
    <div class="caixaUsuarioId">Usuário ID: `+postUserId+`</div>
    `;

Comment: Muito bom amigo, sucesso ai no seu projeto !

Answer (score 1):

Simples assim queridão!

repare como é feita a construção:

```
        // Aqui eu desejo criar um laço que crie uma janela de post para cada "resultado" obtido...
        let element = "";
        for (let index = 0; index < response1.length; index++) {
            element = `
              <div>
                <h1>title: ${response1[index].title}</h1>
                <p>body: ${response1[index].body}</p>
              </div>
            `;

          }
   document.getElementById("divResultado").innerHTML = element;
```

```js
var usuarioId = document.getElementById("usuarioId");
var postId = document.getElementById("postId");
var tituloPost = document.getElementById("tituloPost");
var descricaoPost = document.getElementById("descricaoPost");

var idUsuario = document.getElementById("idUsuario");
document.getElementById("botaoBuscaId").onclick = RequisicaoPorUsuario;

function RequisicaoPorUsuario() {

    var HttpClient = function () {
        this.get = function (aUrl, aCallback) {
            var anHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
            anHttpRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (anHttpRequest.readyState == 4 && anHttpRequest.status == 200)
                    aCallback(anHttpRequest.responseText);
            }
            anHttpRequest.open("GET", aUrl, true);
            anHttpRequest.send(null);
        }
    }

    //puxa o id do usuário informado
    var usuarioId = idUsuario.value;

    //concatena a url de busca com o ID do Usuário informado
    var url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/?userId="+usuarioId;

    var client = new HttpClient();
    client.get(url, function (response) {
        var response1 = JSON.parse(response);
        console.log(response1[0]);
        
        // Aqui eu desejo criar um laço que crie uma janela de post para cada "resultado" obtido...
        let element = "";
        for (let index = 0; index < response1.length; index++) {
            element = `
              <div>
                <h1>title: ${response1[index].title}</h1>
                <p>body: ${response1[index].body}</p>
              </div>
            `;
              
          }
   document.getElementById("divResultado").innerHTML = element;

    });
}
```

```css
body{
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
.caixaPost {
    float: left;
    background-color: rgb(138, 180, 75);
    width: 50%;
    height: auto;
}
.caixaUsuarioId {
    padding: 1%;
    float: left;
    margin: 1%;
    background-color: aliceblue;
}
.caixaPostId {
    padding: 1%;
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    margin: 1%;
    background-color: aliceblue;
}
.caixaTituloPost {
    padding: 1%;
    width: 96%;
    float: left;
    margin: 1%;
    background-color: white;
}

.caixaDescPost{
    padding: 1%;
    width: 96%;
    float: left;
    margin: 1%;
    background-color: white;
    text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilo.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Teste Estágio - 2019</title>
</head>

<body>
    <button id="botaoBuscaId">Buscar por id</button>
    <input type="text" id="idUsuario">
    <div class="caixaPost" id="caixaPost">

        <div class="caixaUsuarioId">Id Usuário:
            <span id="usuarioId">X</span>
        </div>
        <div class="caixaPostId">Id post:
            <span id="postId">X</span>
        </div>
        <div class="caixaTituloPost">Título:
            <span id="tituloPost">XXX</span>
        </div>
        <div class="caixaDescPost">Descrição:
            <span id="descricaoPost">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
                standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it
                to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic
                typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset
                sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker
                including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="divResultado"></div>
    <script src="scriptAPI.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Perfeito Julio, o caminho que eu estou procurando é exatamente esse, mas ainda resta um problema, ele ta listando somente a última resposta da requisição. Pelo que observei ele esta rodando um loop perfeito, mas ao escrever o próximo elemento acaba sobre escrevendo o primeiro elemento escrito.